# Magento 2 : Get shipping method using observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email

I am trying to get the the shipping method using observer but I cant seem to get it to work, this is what I have for the ShippingTypeEmail.php

```
<?php

namespace vendor\Emails\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
class ShippingTypeEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        
    {
    $shpvar =''
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $ShpMethod = $order->getShippingMethod();
    if($ShpMethod == 'flatrate_flatrate'){
      $shpvar = 'flat'
    }else{
        $shpvar = 'collect'
    }
    }
}
```

Then I am using `{{var shpvar|raw}}` on the template

my event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="vendor_emails_variable_order" instance="vendor\Emails\Observer\ShippingTypeEmail" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use sales_order_save_after event to pull the shipping method instead of `email_order_set_template_vars_before`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I presume if I use sales_order_save_after if an order email is resent it would not use the custom variable?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working

```
<?php

namespace vendor\Emails\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ShippingTypeEmail implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $ShpMethod = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
    
        
        if($ShpMethod->getOrder()->getshippingmethod() == 'flatrate_flatrate')
        {
            $ShpMethod['shpvar']  = 'flat';
        }
        else{
            $ShpMethod['shpvar']  = 'collect';
    }
    }
}
```